# Capybara unable to find file input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

Why isn't Capybara (2.8.0) able to find my file input? (The input is present if I inspect `page.body` from a debugger.)

```
And(/^if I add a large image$/) do
  within all('.title').first do
    attach_file('.file-input', test_file)
  end
end

# Cucumber error message
And if I add a large image # features/step_definitions/story_steps.rb:466
  Unable to find file field ".file-input" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
  ./features/step_definitions/story_steps.rb:468:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  ./features/step_definitions/story_steps.rb:467:in `/^if I add a large image$/'
  features/long_form_features.feature:450:in `And if I add a large image'
```

EDIT: I'm able to find the input using an ID (`attach_file 'file_input', test_file`
), but I'd really prefer not to have to add IDs to all of my inputs just to make this test work. Is there any way to use the existing classes in conjunction with Capybara?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the actual file input element is hidden from view on the page.  This is often done to allow for styling of file inputs identically across multiple platforms.  Use `#execute_script` to remove whatever CSS on the input makes it non-visible on the page, and then call `#attach_file` on it.

Update:  I hadn't noticed you were trying to use a class to locate the field.  As [documented](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/2.8.0/Capybara/Node/Actions#attach_file-instance_method) `#attach_file` takes the elements name, id, or the text for the associated label to find the element by, not a css selector.  If you really need to find by the class, and have to stay on the version of Capybara you are on, you can do

```
find('.file-input').set(test_file)
```

or if you update to Capybara 2.10+ you should be able to do

```
attach_file(test_file, class: 'file-input')
```

Additionally `within all('.title').first` can just be `within first('.title')` although neither of those will actually wait for the element to appear on the page if necessary and you'd be better off writing it as  `within first('.title', minimum: 1)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not the case.

Comment: @pdoherty926 Updated answer now that I noticed you were trying to use a class name

Comment: Aha, I didn't realize the `class:` option was introduced in 2.10. I tried using that and was met with an invalid key error - which now makes sense.